# pop up modal using jQuery function seems incorrect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

In worker portal, when user login to the system, I should make a pop up modal by asking them your contract end date will expiring within next 6 months based on today date. Are you wish to extend your contract ? The pop up modal only will appear by detecting their contract and compare with today date, if today date and contract end date is within six months then only the pop-up modal will appear. I already knows the worker contract end date .In order to identify their  contract end date, we are taking arrival date compare with the work permit date. If the duration is less than 2 years, the contract end date is the work permit date + 1 year. If the duration is more than 2 years, the  contract end date is equal to work permit date. I have create the jQuery function for this and I feel the formula calculation seems wrong. Can you check and identify my mistake or the issue as I am new to php and jQuery

This is my jQuery function code

```
function checkContractRenewal() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data/fn_getData.php?mod=contractrenewal",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var contractrenewal = data.contractrenewal;

        var currentDate = new Date();
        var contractEndDate = new Date(contractrenewal.contract_end_date);

        var diffMonths = (contractEndDate.getFullYear() - currentDate.getFullYear()) * 12 + contractEndDate.getMonth() - currentDate.getMonth();
        if (diffMonths <= 6) {
            $("#contractRenewalModal").modal("show");
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: In my case, I guess it just my calculation seems incorrect so I need someone to identify where I making mistake